# How do I make multiple columns in the header and footer in Pages?

Tags: macos, pages

Pages for as long as I've used it had 3 column headers and footers. One day I was messing around, and I managed to remove the columns, and make it a single column. Now I can't figure out how to set it back. I'd like to put the section title in the lower left, and the page on the lower right.

I'm using Pages on OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

I've tried inserting a table into the header, Pages 5.5.3 doesn't let you do that.

Comment: Have you tried opening a new document from a template?  What is the result?

Comment: New gets me all 3. So I guess I could copy and paste my whole project to a new document. Kind of hacky though. I can't figure out how I removed them at this point either.